# Positioning 4 divs 2-by-2

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website in which I use a few divs to display data. I need the first 2 divs to be below each other, and the the next 2 should be on the right of that.

I do not have any problems with the first 2 divs, but after that, it becomes tricky. This is what it looks like now:

[image]

as you can see, the first combo of 2 divs (the gauge is in a dive, and the date/time is in a div) are ok, but the next 2 are not in the right place.

Basecaly, there can be a large number of gauge/datetime combo's. When there is room, I like to position 2 next to eachother, and when the screen is to small for that, I want them to display below eachother.

The HTML/css now looks like this:

```
<div class="panel-body">
<a href="http://localhost:8000/chart/116">
   <div id="sensor_116_0" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; float:left;">        </div>
</a>

<div style="display:block;height: 50px; width: 300px; float:left; clear: both;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-dashboard btn-default disabled">2016-07-17 14:42:00</button> 
</div>

<a href="http://localhost:8000/chart/114">
<div id="sensor_114_1" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; float:left;">
</div>
</a>

<div style="display:block;height: 50px; width: 300px; float:left; clear: both;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-dashboard btn-default disabled">2016-07-17 14:42:00</button>
</div>
</div>
```

I've tried various things, but could not get it outlined the way I would like. Any ideas how I could solve this?

Comment: What about using a table?

Comment: is this what you need, not exactly the ans, is this what you need ? https://jsfiddle.net/Manjuboyz/926Ltqt8/

Comment: well yes, that would work, but tables are basically not inentend to be used for layout purposes (except for when you display a table of data), so I'd like to do it the proper way with CSS

Comment: @ErikL Absolutely correct. However, are you familiar with the `display: table` layout model?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works, this might need some tweak, I guess you can fix those i believe, if not let me know.

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
 <div class="A">
  hello A    
  </div>
  <div class="B">
  hello B
  </div>
  <div class="C">
   hello C
   </div>
   <div class="D">
   hello D
   </div>
   </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content{
 width:500px;
  height:auto;
  background-color:yellow;
  }

 .A, .B, .C, .D{
  width : 45%;
  height: auto;
  float:left;
   background-color: red;
   margin-top:5px;
    }

  .span_to_add{

   margin-top:10px;
    }

   .B, .D{
   margin-left:5px;
   }
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Manjuboyz/926Ltqt8/1/)